# Clientside validation in YII on button(not submit) click or while filling forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, yii

Actually am new to YII, I have a page with **Form** and **JQGrid**. whenever the user clicks **ADD button**, Forms values should be added a row in JQGrid. This functionality I did. But I want to validate the form data while clicking ADD button in JQuery.

[image: Please Find the snapshot of this page]

Kindly help me to validate form values in client side either javascript or JQuery.

Comment: see this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/466/a-simple-way-to-get-yii-client-side-form-validation-run-when-submitting-by-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included HTML5 Validations into form and made the ADD button as submit, In JQuery i did the following changes,

```
$('#btnAdd').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
// Logic to add the form values into grid row.
});
```

So It works as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your form view where your are initializing the form

```
....
'enableClientValidation' => true,
   'clientOptions'=>array(
     'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    )
));
```

Refer to this documentation for more details http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#enableClientValidation-detail

Comment: Actually i don't submit the form values to controller. While clicking ADD button, the JQuery click event will be fired, there i have prevented the submit event and take the form values and then add it as a row into JQGrid.

Comment: In that case you will have to write the validations manually. You can use a plugin like http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to make it easier. Alternatively you can trigger validation on other events as well such as type,change,blur etc. refer the options for more details on other types of client validations